# Is __exit__ called when using in parameter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, file

In this single line code, When call a method as parameter, but not release resource, `__exit__` is called when method is finished ?

```
hashlib.md5(open("PATH", 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
```

It can be issued about 'improper resource release' ?

Comment: no, the `__exit__` method will not be called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__exit__` won't be called, `__exit__` is triggered at the end of [`with-statement`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

In CPython [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) will get triggered eventually as there are no reference to this file object anymore and [it will close the file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#l612).

But it's recommended to use [`with-statement`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to make sure the `close()` call is explicit not implicit and in this way you're not relying on implementation details.

```
with open("PATH", 'rb') as f:
    hash = hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a comprehensive explanations regard this in python [data models documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html):

> Some objects contain references to “external” resources such as open files or windows. It is understood that these resources are freed when the object is garbage-collected, but since garbage collection is not guaranteed to happen, such objects also provide an explicit way to release the external resource, usually a `close()` method. Programs are strongly recommended to explicitly close such objects. The `try...finally` statement and the `with` statement provide convenient ways to do this.

That said your opened object will not be closed since you're not calling the `close` attribute of the opened object. If you don't call the close explicitly you should wrap your code within a `with` statement:

```
with open("PATH", 'rb') as f:
    hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest()
```

By doing the context manager will call `__exit__` method automatically at the end of the block which it will call the close method of your file object consequently.